# Android apk version name

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, version

Following is my `build.gradle` file:

```
...
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "app.com.foo.player"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1 // increment with every release
    versionName "Foo-1.0" // change with every release
    setProperty("archivesBaseName", "$versionName")
    testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'

}
...
```

I have few question related to version name of android apk:

1. When I build the project, the generated apk name is Foo-1.0-debug.apk. Where from is 'debug' coming from, what does it signify, and how do I avoid/change that ?
2. How do I generate different names for dev and prod version of apps ?
3. Is there a way I can automatically increment my version number and version name for each build ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Debug is coming from the flavor you built.  A debug flavor can be attached to by a debugger, and generally will have fewer optimizations on the code.  A release flavor will be fully optimized by the compiler and may not work with a debugger.

If you change to the other flavor, it will say release instead of debug.  Its a good idea to know what type you're using, so I would advise against removing that.  But you can rename the apk to anything you want, its just a file.

Comment: A small clarification - debug or release matters only when it's being run via IDE, right ? Rest all cases wouldn't the app would run in release mode by default ?

Comment: No, not at all.  A release build will have symbols stripped, different proguard rules applied, and frequently different compiler optimization levels.  They may be the same, but I wouldn't count on that.

Comment: How to obtain release build generated apk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With question 1 and 2 you can goto Project Structure select tab Flavors and Build Type to setup config for build.

With question 3 you can make a script in build.gradle in project then use in module. Here I use current time in second as a example:
in project:

```
ext{
    minSdk = 14
    targetSdk = 23
    verCode = getVersion();
    verName = "Foo-1.0"
}
def getVersion() {
    return new Date().getTime() / 1000;
}
```

In module

```
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion minSdk
        targetSdkVersion targetSdk
        versionCode verCode 
        versionName verName + verCode
    }
```

Comment: "make a script in build.gradle in project then use in module" - What are scripts and modules in reference to build.gradle ? Can you please elaborate on this ?

Comment: About script use in build.gradle file you can refer to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html

Answer (score 3):

To generate different name for developmen and product, u can use  productFlavors,refer the below link.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

In gradle ,

```
   productFlavors{
    releaseBuild{
        buildConfigField "String", "APP_NAME", '"SAMPLE_APP_PRODUCT"'
    }

    debugBuild{
        buildConfigField "String", "APP_NAME", '"SAMPLE_APP_DEBUG"'

    }
}
```

After setting in gradle, change the BuiltVariant and run the program